# How save Stack to SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, stack

In my Android app I have a custom stack for Strings which extends [Stack](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Stack.html). I would like to save the stack to Sharedpreferences and also retrieve it from SharedPreferences.

I know how to convert a stack to an ArrayList but I've read that SharedPreferences only supports sets not lists. So how can I save a stack to SP while preserving its order? And how can I retrieve it from SharedPreferences and rebuild the stack?

I'm really lost as to how to approach this. Any pointers in the right direction are highly appreciated - I'm not asking for code dump answers.

Comment: You will probably have to serialize/deserialize your `Stack` to a string representation, which can then be stored in the `SharedPreferences`. It might be possible to (ab)use the json format for this, but it does no give any guarantees about the ordering of the individual elements in the result. It should be easy enough to include the 'position' for every element too though, which you can then use to sort the elements after deserializing. Alternatively, you can come up with your own structure.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. Pls write it up as an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per earlier comment:

You will probably have to serialize/deserialize your `Stack` to a string representation, which can then be stored in the `SharedPreferences`.

It might be possible to (ab)use the json format for this, but it does not give any guarantees about the ordering of the individual elements in the result. It should be easy enough to include the 'position' for every element too though, which you can then use to sort the elements after deserializing.

Alternatively, you can come up with your own structure.

Comment: Thanks. A String representation is the approach I went with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution,

You can convert stack to string via serialization and save the string to shared preference

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(stack);
oos.flush();
String base64str = Base64.encode(bos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
...
```

When load string from preference, decode the base64 string to bytes and using ObjectInputStream to deserialize the stack.